# Input not showing text after first letter

Tags: css, html-framework-7

I'm building a mobile web application and the input forms I've made currently don't show any text after the first letter.
After any kind of scrolling or touch the letters show in the box,

I'm building the application in Framework7, although none of the attributes from the framework contribute to this particular section, as far as I know.

Anyone know whats going on here? can't find anything related to help

```
.input
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width: 100%;
padding-left: 1em;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);

-webkit-transition: color .1s ease, border-color .1s ease;
transition: color .1s ease, border-color .1s ease;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border-radius: 50px;
 padding: 0.6em 0.9em;
 border: 1px solid rgba(34, 36, 38, 0.15);
 font-family: "Avenir-Next-Reg", Arial, Sans Serif;

 -webkit-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 0.50s ease-in-out;
```

[iphone Safari example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM5dx.png)

Answer (score 0):

I  had the same problem earlier today. Check if you have

-webkit-user-select: none;

inherited by the input and if so remove it